# Why am I unable to result the expected output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve student data from the below code. But the actual output is varying from the expected output. I wrote join conditions as per the below requirement.

Requirement:

- Major Code - Join SR0DAT to SR0PST on STU_ID, AWD_DEG_CD, DEG_AWD_TERM_CD and DEG_SEQ_NUM
- Graduate Progress Data Collection - join with Graduate Progress Data Utility
- Specialization Code - Join SR0DAT to SR0SZT on STU_ID, AWD_DEG_CD, DEG_AWD_TERM_CD and DEG_SEQ_NUM where SR0SZT.COLL_CD <> '' AND join SR0SZT to SR0PST on STU_ID, COLL_CD, MAJOR_CD, DEG_CD AND PROG_STRT_TERM

My code is

```
select *   
from dbo.SR0DAT dt  
left join dbo.SR0PST pt on dt.STU_ID = pt.STU_ID
                        and  dt.AWD_DEG_CD = pt.AWD_DEG_CD
                        and  dt.DEG_AWD_TERM_CD = pt.DEG_AWD_TERM_CD
                        and  dt.DEG_SEQ_NUM = pt.DEG_SEQ_NUM
left join dbo.SR0GPT gt on dt.STU_ID = gt.STU_ID
left join dbo.SR0SZT zt on dt.STU_ID = zt.STU_ID
                        and dt.AWD_DEG_CD = zt.AWD_DEG_CD
                        and dt.DEG_SEQ_NUM = zt.DEG_SEQ_NUM
                        and dt.DEG_AWD_TERM_CD = zt.DEG_AWD_TERM_CD
                        and pt.STU_ID = zt.STU_ID
                        and pt.COLL_CD = zt.COLL_CD
                        and pt.MAJOR_CD = zt.MAJOR_CD
                        and pt.DEG_CD = zt.DEG_CD
                        and pt.PROG_STRT_TERM = zt.PROG_STRT_TERM
where dt.STU_ID = '303001849'
  and zt.COLL_CD ! = ' '
```

Am I using the correct join syntax? Can anybody please help me?

Thank you all for your quick response.sorry for not mentioning those. Actual and expected o/ps are mentioned below.

```
expected:
    303001849   05S AB      1   0780    LS  AB      66F     NULL    NULL    NULL
    303001849   09S MA      1   0249    GD  MA      94F     NULL    NULL    NULL
    303001849   12W PHD     1   0249    GD  PHD     94F 11W 2011-01-10 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL


Actual:
STU_ID  DEG_AWD_TERM_CD AWD_DEG_CD  DEG_SEQ_NUM MAJOR_CD    COLL_CD DEG_CD  PROG_STRT_TERM  ADV_CAND_TERM_CD    ADV_CAND_DT SPCL_CD SPCL_STRT_TERM
303001849   05S AB      1   0780    LS  AB      66F     NULL    NULL    NULL
303001849   05S AB      1   0780    LS  AB      66F 11W 2011-01-10 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL
303001849   09S MA      1   0249    GD  MA      94F     NULL    NULL    NULL
303001849   09S MA      1   0249    GD  MA      94F 11W 2011-01-10 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL
303001849   12W PHD     1   0249    GD  PHD     94F     NULL    NULL    NULL
303001849   12W PHD     1   0249    GD  PHD     94F 11W 2011-01-10 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL
```

Comment: I don't see anything syntactically or logically that is incorrect. However, with the table definition or at least an explanation of what is wrong there is nothing anybody can do here. You need to explain things like "the actual output is varying from the expected output". Is it more rows? Fewer?

Comment: One thing to consider though. You have a left join zt but your where predicate changes that so that it will not return rows that don't have a match because of the way NULL works in a join. It is neither = or != to   single space so it would not be returned.

Comment: If Sean's comments do not give you your answer, try posting a few rows of sample data, the expected output for that data and the actual output for that data.  (You can clean or omit any sensitive information.)  Without seeing how your actual results are differing from your expected results, syntax errors are generally the only things we will be able to find.

Comment: try inner joins instead of left joins

Comment: Thank you jamie,  I tried but not giving accurate

Comment: You need to post your table definitions

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I'm unable to add a comment but Sean Lange nailed it with the left join.  The reason you are getting duplicate entries for each record is because one has a null value for the timestamps and one does not.  You can use either

inner joins which will exclude the null results.  The risk is that if the timestamps should be null and you want to display the record anyways then they will be excluded.

left join where timestamp is not null.  This will only join entries where the timestamp is not null, however if there are no such entries it will return a single null row.

Either way, I would review your data structure.  If this is a one off query you should be fine, but if this will be used regularly then it looks like it is possible for you to get 1 to many relationships down the line which may result in more duplicate rows.